# Spring RedisMap returns null when initialization

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-boot

I'm trying to create `RedisMap` under the package `org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.RedisMap`, but it always returns null. My initialization code is:

```
RedisMap<String, MyClass> redisMap = new DefaultRedisMap<String, MyClass>(
    "key:for:Redis",
    new RedisTemplate<String, MyClass>()
);
```

this is the error message:

> Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.

am I missing something?

Comment: I actually need some more code to see how you initialize the bean. If that's the only code (without any `@Bean` configurations) the `RedisTemplate` fails because it's not properly initialized with a `RedisConnectionFactory`.  Checkout the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [Redisson](https://redisson.org) Map object? Implements `ConcurrentMap` interface and works without any problem:

```
RMap<String, MyClass> map = redisson.get("key:for:Redis");
```